# Iterating through two collections LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

Is it possible to iterate through two collections with LINQ?

I have an `ObservableCollection` I am trying to fill and at the moment I am just using your typical `foreach` loop.

I use one loop to loop through a a `string` array, than with that value I check if each a `bool` value is true and add that value to the Collection.

```
public ObservableCollection<StaffInfo> Display = new ObservableCollection<StaffInfo>();

    public void MasterDataDisplay()
    {
        string[] data = new[] {"a", "b", "c"};

        foreach (var section in data)  
        {
            var filter = Db.StaffInfos.Where(p => p.Section == section);
            foreach (var item in filter)
            {
                if (item.CurrentStaff == true)
                {
                    Display.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to do something like this with a single LINQ query?  Or is what I am doing the best way to do this?

Comment: You aren't looping through collections - you are querying the database for individual values. Why don't you convert your loops into a single query?

Comment: Use the Join method to combine two collections.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  You're basically looking for items where the `CurrentStaff` property is true and the `Section` property is contained in the `data` collection:

```
Display = new ObservableCollection<StaffInfo>(
                 Db.StaffInfos
                   .Where(p => p.CurrentStaff == true
                            && data.Contains(p.Section))
              );
```

The nice thing about `Contains` is that it creates an `IN` clause in SQL, so you can get your data in one query instead of 3.

Comment: UV thanks, I never thought of using `contains` like that.

Comment: How are you referencing `AddRange` to observable collection?

Comment: @KyloRen Sorry, see my edit.  You need to use the constructor to add the data in one shot (versus looping through and calling `Add`).

Comment: Ahh, OK, so I just need to make an extension for that. But , I have never seen an `Addrange` extension. Will have to research that.

Comment: @KyloRen Sure you could, but note that calling `Add` triggers the `CollectionChanged` event, while using the constructor does not.

Comment: @I am using a class to supressNotification notifications, so I will just use that with the extension.

Comment: Thanks, I just succesfully use the `addRange` extension. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your code reads data from the database and checks its value. You don't need to loop to do this, just rewrite your code to execute a single query:

```
var items=from item in  Db.StaffInfos
          where data.Contains(item.Section) && item.CurrentStaff
          select item;
Display.AddRange(items);
```

or the equivalent :

```
var items=Db.StaffInfos
            .Where(item => data.Contains(item.Section) && item.CurrentStaff);
Display.AddRange(items);
```

The "trick" here is `someData.Contains(field)`. Contains gets translated to an `field IN (data1, data2,data3)` clause

Comment: +1, this really makes it clear on how to do something like this. Since the query I posted is just a simplified one. Thanks.

Comment: @KyloRen you should treat any loop that contains data access like a hot potato. There's almost always a way to convert it to a single query that will only perform 1 round-trip. Otherwise you end up with N remote calls